# Better solution to run command inside if?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I want to check something with Jenkins API. The last job status `if` failure, just restart and check every *x* seconds until it succeeds.

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! curl -u admin:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx http://jenkins.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/job/sync/lastBuild/api/json | grep -q 'result":SUCCESS'; do
sleep 5
        if [[ $(curl -u admin:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx http://jenkins.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/job/sync/lastBuild/api/json | grep -q result\":FAILURE) ]]; then
                echo 'build did not succeed, retrying'
                curl -I -u admin:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "http://ts.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/job/sync/build?token=sync"
                sleep 10
        else
                echo "next round"
        fi
  sleep 10
done

echo 'build succeeded'
```

The main problem is, I think that if the job failed not triggered with `if`.

Comment: Your approach to check the success of `curl` sounds odd. I don't know how curl signals failure, but you assume that a string _FAILURE_ is send to **stdout**. A more likely reaction would be that error messages go to **stderr** instead, and/or that curl sets a non-zero exit code to signal failure. I suggest you check the man-page of your version of curl.

Comment: `if` and `while` use the same syntax, and you got the while loop right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what curl delivers as return codes, but I am using

```
command ||
{
    echo "error happened during command"
}
```

with many different commands (scp/sftp and so on).

So, in your case this would be

```
curl -u admin:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx http://jenkins.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/job/sync/lastBuild/api/json ||
{
    echo "build did not succeed"
}
```